# Drop down menu isn't working after putting data from an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am trying to build a COVID-19 tracker app using react and materialize CSS framework. I am trying to get some data using an external API and put them into a drop-down menu. I can **console.log** the results, it is fine. But when I try to put that data into a drop-down menu, that drop-down menu isn't responding. When I tried with hardcoded values it is working fine.

This is my App.js. **I  don't have any components except App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
import M from "materialize-css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { countries: [] };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      const elems = document.querySelectorAll("select");
      M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
    });
    const call = await fetch('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries');
    const result = await call.json();

    const countries = result.map( (country) => (
      {
        name: country.country,
        value: country.countryInfo.iso2
      }
    ));
    this.setState({countries:countries});
    
  };

  render = () => {
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>COVID-19 TRACKER</h3>

        <div className="input-field col s12">
          <select>
            {this.state.countries.map( (country) => {
              return <option value={country.name}>{country.name}</option>
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` should be placed outside your `componentDidMount` override as it is a global event.

Don't use vanilla DOM selection and manipulation like `document.querySelectorAll()` if you want to use React at all, React keeps its own DOM tree and updates it based on state changes. Instead, rely on `render()` re-executing every time the state is changed, so what you want to do is to change the state.

Every time you use `map` to generate lists of items, provide unique `keys` to uniquely identify the items in the React tree. Your data source doesn't provide ISO codes for all elements so it's not a reliable item key. I have used here the index (i.e. counter) from the `map` function but ideally you should aggregate a reliable unique identifier from the data itself.

Here's a working code:

https://jsfiddle.net/vpcz9efq/

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer isn't correct, cause it ignores Materalize; the problem seems to be in the Materalize css. For some reason, the select is rendered correctly, but it has a `display: none;` on it. I just imported a custom css file which has:

```
select {
  display: flex;
}
```

The Materialize select shows correctly with that (you don't need to change anything else from your post)

Comment: I already include ```display: flex``` in my App.css. And also the selected answer is working for me.

Comment: This is 100% the wrong answer. Materialize hides the native select and replaces it with a dropdown & text input - don't guess at the answer!